# Prove for $f(x)$ of period $l$ that $ \int_a^{a+l} f(x)\,dx=\int_0^l f(x)\,dx$ for any $a$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose $f(x)$ is periodic with period $l$ and integrable. Prove that, for any $a$ $$ \int_a^{a+l} f(x)\,dx=\int_0^l f(x)\,dx.$$.

i was thinkikng of using definate integral properties such as, $\int_0^l f(x)\,dx =F(l)-F(0) = F(l)$. and  $\int_a^{a+l} f(x) = F(a+l) -F(a)$

now the idea is to break $F(a+l)$ to get $F(a) + F(l)$ is this even true.

any idea of how to approach it

Comment: Hint: No differentiation, simply *two changes of variable and nothing else*. Assume that $a\leqslant k\ell<a+\ell$ for some integer $k$ and note that $$\int_a^{a+\ell}f(x)dx=\int_a^{k\ell}f(x)dx+\int_{k\ell}^{a+\ell}f(x)dx=\int_{a-(k-1)\ell}^{k\ell-(k-1)\ell}f(x)dx+\int_{k\ell-k\ell}^{a+\ell-k\ell}f(x)dx=\,...$$

Comment: @chanler i do not really get the hint

Comment: [Can you be any more specific?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKQGT8Qc8Wo)

Comment: the changing variables

Comment: Try $x\to x-(k-1)\ell$ in the first one and $x\to x-k\ell$ in the second one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your edit contains a very good idea!

Let $F(x) = \int_x^{x + l}f(t)\,dt$. Notice that by the FTC, $F'(x) = f(x + l) - f(x) = 0$ by the assumption that $f$ is $l$-periodic.
 This proves that $F$ is constant. Then in particular $F(0) = F(a)$, which is exactly the desired equality, indeed $$\int_0^lf(t)\,dt = F(0) = F(a) = \int_a^{a + l}f(t)\,dt.$$

---

Comment: I am thinking that but i don't see how that is one of the reason i post it

Comment: @user146269: I have edited to include all the details.

Comment: that makes perfect sense thanks Giovanni

Comment: @user146269: I am glad I could help. I have noticed that you asked 82 questions but you have not accepted a single answer. Please read this (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and start accept all the good answers you have received so far :)

Comment: @user146269: you have not accepted my answer, you probably upvoted it, it is a different thing. There should be a check mark you can click right below the down vote button, that's what you have to click to accept an answer. Also, you get reputation by doing so! it should be +2 rep for each accepted answer.

Comment: oh i see thanks again my friend

Answer (score 2):

We have:
$\int_0^{a+l}f(x)dx=\int_0^{a}f(x)dx+\int_a^{a+l}f(x)dx.$

Now, using the periodicity of $f$ and a change of variable we can re-write the second member of the equality:

$\int_0^af(x)dx=\int_0^af(x+l)dx=\int_l^{a+l}f(s)ds$.

So, we get

$\int_0^{a+l}f(x)dx=\int_l^{a+l}f(s)ds+\int_a^{a+l}f(x)dx.$

and then

$\int_a^{a+l}f(x)dx=\int_0^{a+l}f(x)dx-\int_l^{a+l}f(x)dx=\int_0^lf(x)dx$

Comment: I think you have the limits wrong in the integrations

Comment: Yep, you are right: now I think it's correct.